# How to include a php page through javascript and update it every so often?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page on which I want to include another php page and update this page every 1 second. I try to include it using javascript and .load but it doesn't work. A solution doesn't have to involve using javascript and php, I'm just looking for a way to show who's online on my forum.

test1.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        setInterval(function () {
            $("#show-time").load("test2.php");

        }, 1000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="show-time"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

test2.php

```
<?php
echo time();
```

Comment: Well you are trying to use jQuery without including the jQuery library, your code should be throwing up errors in the javascript console

Comment: Have you checked the docs?  There's an example of exactly what you're trying to achieve here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Although this is probebly not the way to update who's online on your website, your code works perfectly fine except for the fact that you didn't include the jQuery library.

Comment: thank you, I didn't know about the jQuery library not working by default